# MySQL Data Source not appearing in Visual Studio 2015 enterprise edition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mysql-workbench

Installed the ADO.NET connector from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
also tried some other connectors like
connector/net drivers 6.6.5
connector/net drivers 6.8 etc, also downloaded mysql for visualstudio plugin 1.1.1. But MySQL doesn't appear as a data source like it should. I tried restarting Visual Studio. It doesn't fix my issue.

I am currently using window10 (64bit), VS 2015 enterprise edition and mysql-workbench-community-6.3.8-winx64.
[The image is Screen shot of my Visual Studio data connection page where I am not able to see mysql option in 'Choose data source'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhNHe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install the "MySQL for Visual Studio" plugin. MySQL Workbench does not interact with Visual Studio, nor does any connector.

Comment: Thanku. I installed mysqlfor visualstudio plugin 1.2.6 and mysql server5.7.That solved my problem.